# How to uninstall Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm trying to install Rails on my system using:

```
gem install rails
```

But I got this error:

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro-2:/ sammy$ gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/sammy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/ext/nokogiri
/Users/sammy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170716-20185-7bepnp.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.2.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4
with the following patches applied:
  - 0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch
  - 0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-to.patch
  - 0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-ranges.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running git apply with /Users/sammy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/patches/libxml2/0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/sammy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-to.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Users/sammy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/patches/libxml2/0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-ranges.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/Users/sammy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
  CC       error.lo
  CC       parserInternals.lo
  CC       parser.lo
  CC       tree.lo
  CC       hash.lo
  CC       list.lo
  CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/Users/sammy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
  --help
  --clean
  --use-system-libraries
  --enable-static
  --disable-static
  --with-zlib-dir
  --without-zlib-dir
  --with-zlib-include
  --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
  --with-zlib-lib
  --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
  --enable-cross-build
  --disable-cross-build
/Users/sammy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:400:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
  from /Users/sammy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:371:in `chdir'
  from /Users/sammy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:371:in `execute'
  from /Users/sammy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:114:in `compile'
  from /Users/sammy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.2.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:153:in `cook'
  from extconf.rb:365:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
  from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
  from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
  from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
  from extconf.rb:364:in `block in process_recipe'
  from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
  from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
  from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/sammy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sammy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sammy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.0/gem_make.out
```

I've tried to uninstall Nokogiri using:

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
```

then re-running:

```
gem install rails
```

but I got the same error.

I even tried to find and delete every directory that has "nokogiri" in it and then reran the command, getting the same error.

Why is Nokogiri not going away?

Comment: Nokogiri is required by recent versions of Rails--several of the component gems (such as `actionpack` and `actionview`) require `rails-dom-testing`, which in turn requires Nokogiri. So you'll need to get Nokogiri installed or use an older version of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in uninstalling Nokogiri, but on installing it. Rails requires Nokogiri in order to work, but you probably lack of the required libs on your system and that prevents nokogiri from being installed. You may also have an unstable library installed on your system that fails the extension compilation.

I do a quick search based on your error logs and found  this issue: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1483, however, it may or may not the same issue you encountered, but it's worth a check.

The solution from that issue is to uninstall the `xz` package.

```
brew uninstall xz
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Nokogiri installation tutorial, which addresses your reported issue explicitly:

[tutorials](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x)